# Constraining a moving Object

Tags: java, constraints, game-physics

I am new to programming still so I am just playing around with an infinite runner game I would like to make. I have my character image added and a moving block that he has to try to get over. Currently I have it so that if the character collides with the block, his velocity will be 0 so he can't move through the object. But my KeyListener overrides this. So once the block hits the character, he stops moving for 1 game tick, but then the KeyListener proceeds to increase his velocity if you have the key held down and he moves straight through the block. I can't figure out how to fix this.

Here is my player class which handles the players movement as well as the constraints.

```
package runner;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Player implements KeyListener {

public static int playerX = 35;
public static int playerY = 285;
public static int playerWidth = 100;
public static int playerHeight = 100;
public static int playerVX, playerVY;

public static void update() {
    playerX += playerVX;
    playerY += playerVY;

    constrain();
}

public static void paint(Graphics g) {
    //g.setColor(Color.white);
    //g.fillRect(playerX, playerY, 100,100);
}

public static void constrain() {
    if (playerX + playerWidth >= Obstacle.getX() && playerX <= 
Obstacle.getX() + Obstacle.width && playerY + playerHeight >= 
Obstacle.getY()) {
        playerX = 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        playerVX = -5;
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        playerVX = 5;
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        playerVY = -5;
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        playerVY = 5;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        playerVX = 0;
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        playerVX = 0;
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        playerVY = 0;
    }
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        playerVY = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's a bunch of my code, it doesn't work, can someone help me figure it out"_ are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information, and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157).  Have you placed breakpoints in your code to see what is actually happening?

Comment: I figured since I am just missing something small this question would be appropriate. I have put breakpoints in my code. Once the character collides with the  block the Velocity is set to 0 but the next game tick you can use the KeyListener to increase the velocity which sends the character straight through the block

Comment: Well, you know what is happening, modify your code to prevent that from happening by checking in the key listener if it is possible to move in the selected direction.

Comment: The key events should just be used just to get the current keyboard state. IE `keys[keyCode] ==true;` for up events and `keys[keyCode] = false` for down events. Then in your game's main loop you check the key states in response to the game`s state. If the player is trapped you ignore the key events for that direction `if(!player.blocked && keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT]){ ... move player }else{... stop player}`

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a game at the moment and was having the same trouble (I also am new to game programming). I came up with a few methods and such to deal with collisions.

This method would go in your player class:

```
public void applyBound(Bound bound) {
    if (bound.x1 != null) {
        if (x <= bound.x1) {
            x = bound.x1;
        }
    }
    if (bound.x2 != null) {
        if (x >= bound.x2 - width) {
            x = bound.x2 - width;
        }
    }
    if (bound.y1 != null) {
        if (y <= bound.y1) {
            y = bound.y1;
        }
    }
    if (bound.y2 != null) {
        if (y >= (bound.y2 - height)) {
            y = bound.y2 - height;
        }
    }
}
```

Where Bound is:

```
public class Bound {
    public Integer x1, x2, y1, y2;

    public Bound(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    public Bound(Integer x1, Integer x2, Integer y1, Integer y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }
}
```

"applyBound(boxBounds)" would be the last thing called each time you update your player.

- "Bound.x1" is the left most position that the player can go.
- "Bound.x2" is the right most position
- "Bound.y1" is the bottom most position and
- "Bound.y2" is the top most position

Bounds can be null so you do not need for example a top bound.

In the Bound class, you can put, for example, the bounds of the screen so that the player can't go off, or you could put in the edges of another character.

**You need to use a variable to see whether the key is pressed or not and add the velocity in the update method.**

Hope this helps!